# How to find a value by searching for a string within an array within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following object:

```
data = [
  {
    type: "fruit",
    basket: ["apple", "pear", "orange"]
  },
  {
    type: "vegetable",
    basket: ["carrot", "potato"]
  }
];
```

I wish to search the data for 'potato' and have returned 'vegetable'. I am hoping to use filter or map, but I'm struggling with the syntax. Vanilla javascript please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is

```
var res = data.map(
    x => x.basket.indexOf("potato") === -1 ? undefined : x.type
).filter(x => x !== undefined);
```

`res` will be a list of all matching `type`s (there can be more than one if the same value is contained multiple times. You can use `res[0]` if you're sure the values are unique and in that case you'll get either the `type` value or `undefined` when it's not present.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Array#find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to iterate over each object and using [**Array#some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to iterate over each basket and check if there is an item with name `potato`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: "fruit",
    basket: ["apple", "pear", "orange"]
  },
  {
    type: "vegetable",
    basket: ["carrot", "potato"]
  }
];

const itemWithSome = data.find(item => item.basket.some(i => i === 'potato'));

console.log(itemWithSome.type);

const itemWithIncludes = data.find(item => item.basket.includes('potato'));

console.log(itemWithIncludes.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var data = [{ type: "fruit", basket: ["apple", "pear", "orange"] }, { type: "vegetable", basket: ["carrot", "potato"] }],
    find = 'potato';

console.log(data.find(o => o.basket.includes(find)).type);
```